# In Kubernetes - grant permissions to list namespaces (only)

Tags: kubernetes, permissions, kubectl

I am trying to workaround an issue with a third party tool.  That tool needs to be able to ensure that the namespace I tell it to work in exists.  To do that, it runs:

```
kubectl get namespace my-namespace-name-here
```

The user that I let the third party tool run as has `edit` permissions in the `my-namespace-name-here` namespace.  (Via a `rolebinding` to the namespace using the `clusterrole` called `edit`.)

But edit permissions is not enough to allow it to check (using that command) if the namespace exists.

Ideally, I would like a way to grant the user permissions to just get the one namespace above.  But I would be satisfied if I could grant permissions to just list namespaces and nothing else new at the cluster level.

**How can I just add permissions to list namespaces?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!

I needed to make a `Role` scoped to `my-namespace-name-here` that grants the ability to get namespaces.  Then make a `rolebinding` to grant that permission to my user.  Running a `kubectl apply -f  ./my-yaml-file-below.yaml` did it.

Here is the yaml

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:  
  name: namespace-reader
  namespace: my-namespace-name-here
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["namespaces"]
  verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1"
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-username-here-namespace-reader
  namespace: my-namespace-name-here
roleRef:
  apiGroup: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  kind: Role
  name: namespace-reader
subjects:
  - apiGroup: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind: User
    name: "my-username-here@mydomain.com"
```

This allows the user to do a `kubectl get namespace` only the the namespace that this is granted on.

Comment: You can even set the `resouceName` If you want to constraint to one namespace